# Linq SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am coding my way through the MS 101 linq examples.

The "JoinOperators" are giving me a hard time since I am trying to refactor the query expressions to lambda syntax and vice versa.

Anyway, on example [105](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) I see this query expression:

```
var supplierCusts =
    from sup in suppliers
    join cust in customers on sup.Country equals cust.Country into cs
    from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()  // DefaultIfEmpty preserves left-hand elements that have no matches on the right side 
    orderby sup.SupplierName
    select new
    {
        Country = sup.Country,
        CompanyName = c == null ? "(No customers)" : c.CompanyName,
        SupplierName = sup.SupplierName
    };
```

And I tried implementing it as a lambda this way:

```
// something is not right here because the result keeps a lot of "Join By" stuff in the output below
var supplierCusts =
    suppliers.GroupJoin(customers, s => s.Country, c => c.Country, (s, c) => new { Customers = customers, Suppliers = suppliers })
        .OrderBy(i => i.Suppliers)    // can't reference the "name" field here?
        .SelectMany(x => x.Customers.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, p) =>    // does the DefaultIfEmpty go here?
            new
            {
                Country = p.Country,
                CompanyName = x == null ? "(No customers)" : p.CompanyName,
                SupplierName = p    // not right: JoinOperators.Program+Customer ... how do I get to supplier level?
            });
```

For some reason I can't access the supplier-level information this way. When I switch out the `customers` with `suppliers` I can't access the customer-level information.

Is there some overload of `SelectMany()` that lets me pull from the field-level of both objects?

Also, I don't understand why the `GroupJoin()` appears to return an object with 2 collections (`suppliers` and `customers`). Isn't it supposed to join them somehow?

I guess I don't understand how `GroupJoin()` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have wrong result selector in group join, that's where problems started. Here is fixed query:

```
var supplierCusts =
   suppliers
     .GroupJoin(customers, 
                sup => sup.Country, 
                cust => cust.Country, 
                (sup, cs) => new { sup, cs })
     .OrderBy(x => x.sup.Name)    
     .SelectMany(x => x.cs.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, c) =>
        new
        {
            Country = x.sup.Country,
            CompanyName = c == null ? "(No customers)" : c.CompanyName,
            SupplierName = x.sup.Name   
        });
```

Comment: Every time I try a query like this, I get the error, "The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method." What's up with that?

Comment: @Boydski never faced that error before. Can you post your problem as question with steps to reproduce?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336653/outer-join-with-linq-causing-groupjoin-error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn translating the query expressions into lambda's, I suggest you check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) which can do that by default. For example, your query is translated as follows:

```
    Suppliers
   .GroupJoin (
      Customers, 
      sup => sup.Country, 
      cust => cust.Country, 
      (sup, cs) => 
         new  
         {
            sup = sup, 
            cs = cs
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp0 => temp0.cs.DefaultIfEmpty (), 
      (temp0, c) => 
         new  
         {
            temp0 = temp0, 
            c = c
         }
   )
   .OrderBy (temp1 => temp1.temp0.sup.CompanyName)
   .Select (
      temp1 => 
         new  
         {
            Country = temp1.temp0.sup.Country, 
            CompanyName = (temp1.c == null) ? "(No customers)" : temp1.c.CompanyName, 
            SupplierName = temp1.temp0.sup.CompanyName
         }
   )
```

That being said, I typically find SelectMany to be easier to code and maintain using the query syntax instead of the lambda syntax.

The GroupJoin in this example is used to accomplish the left join (via the .DefaultIfEmpty clause).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var supplierCusts =
    suppliers.GroupJoin(customers, s => s.Country, c => c.Country, (s, c) => new { Supplier = s, Customers = c })
        .OrderBy(i => i.Supplier.SupplierName)
        .SelectMany(r => r.Customers.DefaultIfEmpty(), (r, c) => new
        {
            Country = r.Supplier.Country,
            CompanyName = c == null ? "(No customers)" : c.CompanyName,
            SupplierName = r.Supplier.SupplierName
        });
```