# Outer join with Linq causing "GroupJoin" error

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011, left-join, outer-join, xrm

The following join projection is throwing the error, ***"The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method."*** I've run over a few permutations of changes, but haven't been able to figure it out. Thoughts?

EDIT: It's looking more and more like this ***may be a Dynamics CRM issue***. The Xrm models I'm accessing for data have been generated by the CRM SDK (CRM 2011).

```
var q =
   left
     .GroupJoin(right, 
                c => c.Id, 
                cl => cl.c.Id, 
                (c, cs) => new { c, cs })
     .Where(x=>x.c.Name.Contains("some text"))
     .SelectMany(x => x.cs.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, csubl) =>
        new
        {
            CompanyName = x.c.Name
        });
```

Comment: Just verified both with EF and Linq to Objects - works fine as expected. That's definitely issue of dynamics CRM

Comment: Yep. I've already figured that out. Yay for me.  :(

Answer (score 0):

i think in query syntax it will be more beautiful

```
var q = from l in left
        join r in right on l.Id equals r.c.Id into groupped
        from g in groupped.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where l.Name.Contains("some text")
        select new { 
            CompanyName = l.Name; 
        }
```

**UPDATE**
in samples from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334593.aspx) have sample with left join, so you can try my code above, or move `Where` before `GroupJoin` or after `SelectMany`